# Few packages from "node_modules" are missing. How? Why? Where?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, node-modules

As part of my debugging process and while trying to solve another issue, I stumbled upon the following:

```
[Busy] Launching SocketCluster
1538304734910 - Origin: Worker (PID 43804)
   [Error] Error: Compilation of µWebSockets has failed and there is no pre-compiled binary available for your system. Please install a supported C++11 compiler and reinstall the module 'uws'.
    at native (/Users/antonmladenov/Documents/Coding Fitness/GraphQL/client/node_modules/uws/uws.js:38:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/antonmladenov/Documents/Coding Fitness/GraphQL/client/node_modules/uws/uws.js:42:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at new SCServer (/Users/antonmladenov/Documents/Coding Fitness/GraphQL/client/node_modules/socketcluster-server/scserver.js:96:18)
```

My focus was on two packages in particular -

- `uws`: (`/node_modules/uws/uws.js:38:19`);
- `socketcluster-server`: (`/node_modules/socketcluster-server/scserver.js:96:18`)

So, I looked for them manually, I walked through the whole package tree of `node_modules` and the packages are simply not there.

My questions are:

1. Are they really missing?
2. If No, where are these packages?
3. If Yes, why do I see their specific paths?

Comment: Are these dependancies in `package.json`? Have you ran `npm install` so you get all dependencies? Note that if another developer added the code that uses them or even if it was you but on a different machine, they might have been installed globally, which means that the project would run on that machine alone. Hence why they need to be added to `package.json` instead of runnint `npm install --global` when adding a package.

Comment: no, @vlaz. they are not part of `package.json`, they are dependencies of the modules that are part of it. 
well, I did `yarn` and `yarn upgrade` and `yarn what-not` but no success yet.